# programmatically creating documents and assigning data to them in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, I have a block of code that loops through a table of transactions looking for unique values, and then creates a table based on those unique values.  For example,

```
Lucy ~ CA ~ Likes Monty Python
Lucy ~ CA ~ Plays the Ukulele
Abby ~ FL ~ Owns a submarine
```

The code that I have will read the unique values from the table and create an xlsx named Lucy.xlsx and Abby.xlsx.

What I haven't been able to figure out how to do is to take the values that start with Lucy, and copy them into the the table that is named Lucy.xlsx and so forth for the other unique values in the sheet.

I am able to programmatically loop through the files and reopen them.  When nothing copies.

Here's my code.

```
Sub getMetaData()
    ' EVERYTHING SEEMS TO WORK FINE RIGHT HERE '
    Dim home As Workbook
    Set home = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Set sht1 = home.Sheets(1)

    Dim lastSheet As Integer
    lastSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(lastSheet)

    lastSheet = lastSheet + 1

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(lastSheet).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(lastSheet).Name = "Meta Data"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim DirArray As Variant
    DirArray = sht.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value

    Dim arr As New Collection, a
    Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    aFirstArray() = DirArray

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In aFirstArray
        arr.Add a, a
    Next

    Sheets("Meta Data").Select

    For i = 1 To arr.Count
        Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
    Next

    lastArea = arr.Count
    Dim whyArray() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve whyArray(1 To (lastArea))
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    For i = 1 To lastArea
        whyArray(i) = Cells(i, 1)
    Next i

    Dim wb() As Workbook
    ReDim Preserve wb(lastArea)

    For i = 1 To lastArea
        Cells(i, 25) = "Whoop dey it is"
        Cells(i, 26) = whyArray(i)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To lastArea
        wb(i) = Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (whyArray(i))
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i

    Dim wbs() As Workbook
    ReDim Preserve wbs(lastArea)

    For i = 1 To lastArea
        wbs(i) = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & whyArray(i) & ".xlsx")
    Next i

    ' vvv I CAN'T GET THIS TO WORK FOR THE LIFE OF ME vvv '

    For i = 1 To lastArea
        For j = 1 To lastRow
            If whyArray(i) = sht1.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                wbs(i).Sheets(1).Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, lastColumn)).Value = sht1.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, lastColumn))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically `Set` is missing in `Workbooks` operations, so the file handles are not initialized so all subsequent file operations fail. If you had tried running it step by step with F8 you would have noticed the bug.

A few suggestions: 
You need `On Error Resume Next` to manage filtering by collection, but you should reset error handler after. You should also check if the error is just the expected or something else:

```
Dim errnum as long
For Each a In aFirstArray
    On Error Resume Next
    arr.Add a, a
    errnum = Err.Number
    On Error Goto 0
    If errnum <> 0 and errnum <> 457 Then 
       Err.Raise errnum
       Err.Clear
    End If
Next
```

I feel there may be other problems with opening many new files in loop. I would combine the last 3 loops this way to reduce the number of simultaneously open files:

```
For i = 1 To lastArea
    Set wbs = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    For j = 1 To lastRow
        If whyArray(i) = sht1.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            wbs.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, lastColumn)).Value = sht1.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, lastColumn))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    wbs.Close Filename:=MyPath & "\" & whyArray(i) & ".xlsx"  ' save & close
Next i
```

You might misunderstand the purpose of `ReDim Preserve`. It is not bad just redundant using `Preserve` right after declaring an (empty) array.

Comment: I guarantee you I misunderstand ReDim Preserve!  I implemented your solution and I like it a lot, but the values are not copying into the new spreadsheets.